# Can Raider Power Armour have a Jetpack?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm playing Fallout 4 for the first time. I've just got the Overboss armour from Nuka-World and would like to add a jetpack to it. Is this possible?

The mods list doesn't seem to list it, but I don't have Science 4 yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Jetpack mod is only available via crafting at a Power Armor Station, and requires "Science! Rank 4".

You can still obtain one without that perk, according to [Fallout wiki](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Jet_pack_(Fallout_4)):

> T-60 variant can be obtained as a reward for completing the quest [A New Dawn](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/A_New_Dawn).

However, Jetpack mods are craftable only for T-45, T-51, T-60 and X-01 series.

So I don't think it's compatible with *Overboss armour*, here's a [list of torso mods for Raider Power Armor](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Raider_power_armor_(Fallout_4)#Torso).

Comment: Thanks! I figured that was the case, just wanted to check though.